# How to ask for the current token number of the person being served by customercare

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request, phrase-request

In places like banks or other customer care centers, tokens are issued to people and based on the token number, one is served by customer care. At some places, there are automatic displays displaying the current token number being served.

In case, if we have to ask some one at the reception about the current status, how'll we ask the question :-

"Excuse me, can you please let me know the latest token number which is being served (any other better word in place of served ?) ?"

I hope you understand the situation that I am trying to describe here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the kind of sign that says "Now serving", like this:

[image]

we don't call that a "token" in English (although I understand what you mean, because it's a unique identifier).  I would just call it "number" or "customer number", because the usual announcement that the staff make is something like "Now serving customer fifty-two" or "...customer number fifty-two" or just "...number fifty-two."

So I would phrase the question as, **"Excuse me, what number is being served now?"**  I am answering this from the perspective of a US English speaker, specifically a New York City English speaker; English speakers from other places may have different local ways of phrasing it.

Comment: +1 for  _English speakers from other places may have different local ways of phrasing it_  I suspect that there is huge variety in what people say.  I would probably hold up my ticket or point at the display and ask _"What number are you on?"_